# Date picker html5 tag is not working on Mozilla, IE browsers. But its working only on Chrome

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, datepicker, mozilla

I am trying to use HTML 5 Date picker tag in my website. But this tag is not supporting  on Mozilla & IE. Can you please share me any hack to work this code in IE and Mozilla.

I want to use only HTML5. i don't want to go for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Date is only supported in Chrome, Opera, Safari and Android Browser 4.4+

http://beta.caniuse.com/#search=date

Answer (score 2):

You can user jQuery date picker in case of Mozilla: Check the browser using $.browser.mozilla but it will not work in jQuery>1.9, so you have to use jQuery Migration as shown below:

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>//jQuery migration
    <script>
        if ($.browser.mozilla)
    {
        if ($('.datepicker')[0].type != 'date') $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1900:2015",
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                defaultDate: '1900-01-01'
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Note that the OP said *I want to use only HTML5. i don't want to go for JavaScript.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes `DatePicker` tag of HTML5 is not supported by Mozilla Firefox. But you can use `DatePicker` in your website by adding few .js files.

Below is my fiddle using some .js files. this code work properly on Chrome as well as Mozilla.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your Selected date Is : <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vq65z/504/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: ok i got it what you want to say. actualy i am New to stacoverflow that's y i dont know much about answering the questions of overflow. thanx for Suggestion #t3chb0t.

Answer (score 1):

1st, to answer the OP, what the asker is asking to do is impossible. `Javascript` is required. 2nd, although `webshim` looks great, it works horribly with `bootstrap`. For that you'll want to use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Firefox and mozilla does not not supporting Date-HTML5 ! It will support soon.**

---

*But it will work smoothly on **Google-Chrome, Opera and Safari***

Comment: Eirenaios I am using this tag only, but i IE & Mozilla not supporting this tag. So can you tell me any css hack for this?

Comment: jQuery UI is only the way not html5

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a datepicker polyfill. here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/kbQ9E/).

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>

<script>
  //webshim.setOptions('basePath', '/js-webshim/minified/shims/');

  //request the features you need:
  webshim.polyfill('es5 mediaelement forms');

  $(function(){
    // use all implemented API-features on DOM-ready
  });
</script>

<input type="date" />
```